# Wamp authentication required when trying to log from external device

Tags: apache, wamp, port

Wamp authentication required when trying to log from external device
Hello, I am having trouble with reaching my site without having to asked for a username and password by authentication request.
I read a tutorial about how to put my wamp online, (port forwarding and all)
and i just cant figure out why i still having these requests.
I thought about one thing: when i port forwarded i got this popup: [Click me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSszJ.png)
thanks!

Comment: That sounds like you are getting routed to your routers admin panel. Most router also contain a web server so that will need to be reconfigured to run on another port so that port 80 is free and forwardable

Comment: @RiggsFolly but when i put my username and password it's not working so its not the router admin panel... plus i think its something about wamps Apache server

Comment: I would bet that the message you show is from the router, which like I say has a small web server in it

Comment: @RiggsFolly so how do i change the webserver in the router to another port ?

Comment: From the Admin Panel, and by reading the user manual